# deselect text in vim, like grep -v

Tags: visual-studio, vim, vi

I would like to immitate the following pattern of searching in vim:

```
grep "\<[0-9]\>" *  |  grep -v "666"
```

I can highlight all numbers using

```
/\<[0-9]\>"
```

but then how can I tell vim to remove from the highlighted text the ones that match the expression

```
/666
```

Can this be done in Visual Studio at least ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sequentially filter the matches like in the shell, so you need to use advanced regular expression features to combine both into a single one.

Basically, you need to assert a *non-match* of `666` at the match position. That's achieved with the `\@!` atom (in other regular expression dialects, that's often written as `(?!...)`):

```
/\%(\d*666\d*\)\@!\<\d\+\>
```

Note: If you want to **only** exclude `666`, but not `6666` etc. you need to specify `\<666\>` instead in the first part.

I've used `\d` instead of `[0-9]`; you can further strip down the `\` use with the `\v` "very magic" modifier:

```
/\v(\d*666\d*)@!<\d+>
```

Comment: sorry, I've tried both expressions, in `123 123 1236662342 66` and the hole text is highlighted in both cases!  By the way, what does the % in `\%(666\)` do?

Comment: Ah, so you want any occurrence of `666`, also inside numbers! I've adapted the pattern.

Comment: The `\%(` makes this a _non-capturing_ group. It's optional, so I've omitted this in the shortened one, too.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, `/666` doesn't match that expression.

Assuming, though, that you had e.g. `\d\+` and wanted to exclude `666`, you can use the negative lookahead:

```
\v((666)@!\d)+
```

This uses

- `\v` for very magic (reducing the number of `\` escapes)
- `\@!` for "negative zero-width look-ahead assertion"

Comment: in the text `123 123 1236662342 66` the numbers are highlighted like `123` `123` `123`6 `662342` `66`  (ie only the 1st `6` in the number containing 666 is not highlighted)